# Drf token authentication password reset

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, token

I'm wondering whether Django rest framework token authentication has password reset property. I have a Django app where I'm using token authentication to register and login users. But I was told that in order for me to implement password reset in the Django app I have to switch to packages like JWT or Knox. But I would like to use drf token authentication without switching to jwt or Similar package. How should I go about this, is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know the token authentication will only check if the user is authentic with real password, username and/or email. The password reset is managed by django itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or create an endpoint that can send an email to the user containing a link with a token and uid, and another endpoint that takes in the uid and token and resets the password.

```js
@api_view(["GET"])
def send_resetpassword_email(request, email):
    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    if user.is_active == True:
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        subject = "Please Reset your password"
        message = render_to_string(
            "reset_password_email.html",
            {
                "user": user,
                "domain": current_site.domain,
                "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                "token": account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            },
        )
        user.email_user(subject, message)
        return Response(
            {"message": "Reset Password Email Sent"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
    return Response(
        {"message": "user is not active"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    )


class ResetPassword(APIView):
    serializer_class = ResetPasswordSerializer

    def put(self, request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None

        if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user.set_password(request.data.get("password"))
                user.save()
                return Response(
                    {"message": "Password Reset Successfull"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
                )
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(
                {"message": "Password Reset Failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

So you have to create a Reset Password serializer